# Rules. Запрет на использование определенных символов в файле

Tags: yii2

Есть yii2 форма.
Вот правила:

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['path'], 'file','skipOnEmpty' => false, 'extensions' => ['html','htm']],
            [['language'], 'string',],
        ];
    }
```

Необходимо добавить еще одно правило. Чтобы в загружаемом файле не было символов `<?` и `?>`
Подскажите, как это сделать?

Comment: В содержимом файла или в его названии?

Comment: в содержимом файла

Comment: Вытяните содержимое файла и прогоните по содержимому регулярное выражение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам необходимо написать свой валидатор, для проверки содержимого файла. [Здесь](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/ru/input-validation#creating-validators) подробное описание о том как делать свои валидаторы. В вашем случае это будет простой метод, который прочитает содержимое файла и проверит его строковой функцией. Далее пример кода для наглядности.
В метод rules добавить валидатор:

```
['file', 'fileContentValidator'],
```

И ниже метод:

```
public function fileContentValidator()
{
    $content = file_get_contents($this->file->tempName);
    if (strpos($content, '<?') !== false) {
       $this->addError('file', 'Ваше сообщение об ошибке'); 
    }
}
```

Обратите внимание, что свойство `file` должно быть объектом класса `yii\web\UploadedFile`